# initializer, properties, accessors and copy/retain/readonly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties, initialization, accessor

I want to understand how to set the parameters of properties (accessors).

I took the following code from an example of Kal calendar.

```
// Holiday.h

@interface Holiday : NSObject
{
  NSDate *date;
  NSString *name;
  NSString *country;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSString *country;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name country:(NSString *)country date:(NSDate *)date;

@end

// Holiday.m

#import "Holiday.h"

@implementation Holiday

@synthesize date, name, country;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)aName country:(NSString *)aCountry date:(NSDate *)aDate
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    name = [aName copy];
    country = [aCountry copy];
    date = [aDate retain];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [date release];
  [name release];
  [country release];
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

1) The properties are set to `retain`, but since the setter can't be used the `retain` makes no sense here.

2) In addition, in the `initWithName` method the values are set with `copy`. Why not directly defining the properties with `copy` and using the accessor methods?

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
// ...
self.name = aName;
```

3) Do I need the `readonly` here? I don't know why they are used here. If I would use `copy` together with the setter the `readonly` prohibits me to set the value, because there is no setter.

4) In the `initWithName` method sometimes `copy` and sometimes `retain` is used. I would suggest to use always `copy` here, because the value should not get modified later.

5) What I can remember is that it is OK to `copy`/`retain` in the `initWithName` and `release` in the `dealloc` method.

So how would you suggest to use `retain`, `copy` and `readonly` in this example here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***ETA:*** @DougW correctly points out that a property's ownership type (`assign`/`retain`/`copy`) does not affect the getter. It does still affect the setter. For `readonly` types, this matters if you are going to override the `readonly` portion of the declaration in a class extension, so you can use the setter within your implementation. A class extension property override is only allowed to change the `readonly` status of the property, so the rest of it - which means the atomicity and ownership types - must be declared appropriately in the header. Even if you're not overriding the property now, you might in future, so you might as well document how you want the memory managed for yourself by using the correct option to begin with.

Automatic reference counting (ARC) changes the runtime implementation details by overlaying its own memory management rules on top of the classic refcount rules, but the rules and advice for configuring your properties stay the same.

---

**Why use `retain` with `readonly`?** If you mark a property as `retain`, the synthesized accessor does something like this:

```
/* getter for retain property */
- (NSString *)name {
    return [[name retain] autorelease];
}
```

Now, if the object you sent `-name` to changes the name while you're still using it, the calling code will still have a valid reference to a string. If you declared it as `assign`, though, it would be like this:

```
/* getter for assign property */
- (NSString *)name {
    return name;
}
```

Now, as soon as name is changed by the object, it will have to be released to avoid a leak, which will invalidate the calling code's reference. The `retain`/`copy`/`assign` is really stating a memory-management policy: `retain`/`copy` says, "I promise that I hold a reference to the original/a copy of the value I provide here," while `assign` says, "I just have the value and claim no owning reference to this."

When the value doesn't need memory management, such as a plain `int`, then `assign` makes sense. When you're intentionally not retaining an object, such as a delegate, then `assign` makes sense. But, in most other cases, you'll want `retain` or `copy`.

Further, the implementation file can only override the `readwrite`/`readonly` portion of a property declaration, not the memory management portion. As declared, the `.m` file can have:

```
@interface Holiday (/*class extension*/)
@property(nonatomic, retain, readwrite) NSDate *date;
/* override other properties to make them readwrite... */
@end
```

Non-public setters for the overridden property declarations will then be synthesized along with the public accessors.

**Why not use setters/accessors during `-init`?** Because setters/accessors frequently perform KVO notification, which you want to avoid while your object is not fully initialized, i.e., during `-init` (when it's half-initialized on its way to full initialization) and `-dealloc` (when it's half-initialized on its way to being fully un-initialized).

**Why use `copy` with `readonly`?** As in response to your first question: because if `copy` versus `retain` versus `assign` affects both the setters and the getters. A copy getter would look like this:

```
/* getter for copy property */
- (NSString *)name {
    return [[name copy] autorelease];
}
```

**Why sometimes `copy` and sometimes `retain`?** `copy` is generally used with value objects (passive objects representing a value); `retain` is generally used with other objects. Sometimes, efficiency concerns come into play (most likely prematurely...), and you might opt to use `retain` where you would normally use `copy`.

**How would you use `copy`/`retain` along with `readonly` here?** Pretty much as they did. I'd override the declarations in a class extension so I can use setters to change the properties' values outside of `-init` and `-dealloc`, where I would only use direct instance variable access. I would also `nil` out the ivars after releasing them in `-dealloc`, e.g.,

```
[name release], name = nil;
```

This helps avoid sending messages to or otherwise referencing an already-released object.

Comment: **nonatomic** retain properties just return the pointer.  They **do not** do the retain, autorelease thing.  See the **atomicity** section of the docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html

Comment: @JeremyP: Good call. The decision not to `[[foo retain] autorelease]` in non-atomic accessors does makes sense: If you're going to hold onto the value for longer than the current runloop cycle, you should be retaining it yourself. If you're using `nonatomic`, you're basically stating that thread-safety is not a concern. If you don't have to worry about thread-safety, then no code aside from yours will be executing while you are using the return value from the accessor, so it's unnecessary for the accessor to perform `[[foo retain] autorelease]`.

Comment: @Jeremy: I would go so far as to say that using nonatomic means you are stating that robustness is not a concern - or is less of a concern than performance.  Setting properties to nonatomic without first profiling your code counts as a premature optimisation in my book.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman: Many good tips here. Questions: 1) If you override a property declaration how does the compiler know which accessor to use? Through the class extension? 2) Assign also for NSInteger, BOOL, double, float, CLLocationCoordinate2D, ... ?

Comment: @JeremyP: 1) `atomic` is a concern if I'm writing a multithreading application with e.g. `performSelectorInBackground`? Because I'm writing a single threaded app I always should use `nonatomic`? 2) A `retain` property is never retained (only the pointer returned)?

Comment: @testing: (1) The class extension override is not allowed to change anything except `readonly` to `readwrite`. The only change is that a setter is also synthesized. This way, the class declares to the world, "You can get this, but not set it." Then, it tells the compiler, "But I do actually want there to be a setter - the property should not be `readonly` for *me*." (2) Yes, you would use `assign` for those types. They require no memory management.

Comment: @testing: I would always use atomic properties unless profiling showed them to be a performance bottleneck.  As I said, nonatomic properties don't even do the retain autorelease thing mentioned in Jeremy's answer.  That means you can't get a property of an object, release the object and then use the property safely even in a single threaded application.

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman: Why does `int` does not require memory management?

Comment: Because `int`'s aren't reference counted. A plain old `int` property can safely be copied here, there, and everywhere, with no concern for strong or weak references. Heck, read and writes to it most likely don't even need to be locked, because it's small enough that it's always read/written atomically by the underlying instruction set architecture. (That's not to say that you won't get a stale cached value from another thread if you don't use a memory barrier, but you won't get an inconsistent, half-set value regardless.)

Comment: @testing: To put Jeremy W. Sherman's comment another way, memory management only applies to objects - there's no need to worry about it with scalar types like int and float.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman - I believe your part about "copy with readonly" is incorrect.  A "copy" property's getter does **not** copy the outgoing object.  Its setter copies the **incoming** object.  I wanted to make sure, so I created a simple class with an "atomic, copy" property and retrieved the value over and over.  Same memory address every time (and I used a custom class, not one that may return the same address on copy).  In other words, copy and retain property getters are identical.

Comment: @DougW You are correct. @JeremyP pointed this out in the first comment to this question. There's no need to bother with empirical tests: You can see the implementation for yourself in [objc-accessors.m](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m) (that's the Mac OS X 10.7.2 version of the code). The underlying runtime function `objc_getProperty` only cares whether the property is atomic or not, while `objc_setProperty` cares about both atomicity and memory management (retain, copy, mutable copy).

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman - Hey thanks Jeremy.  My main concern though was that the section titled "Why use copy with readonly?" should be removed or edited, since the code snippet there is incorrect.  It states that a copy property's **getter** will be the following: "- (NSString *)name {
return [[name copy] autorelease];
}".  That's simply never the case, atomic, non-atomic, ARC or otherwise.  The link you referenced agrees.  Just don't want folks stumbling across that part and getting confused.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman - Actually now that I re-read it, I think I see why we're misunderstanding each other.  When you wrote "because **it** copy versus retain versus assign affects both the setters and the getters. A copy getter would look like this:".  I assumed you meant "because **its**".  Did you mean "because **if**"?

Comment: @DougW We are understanding each other, and I am saying that you and JeremyP are right, and I was wrong: copy does not affect the getter, only the setter. I added a foreword of sorts to the original answer, but large parts of the answer need to be rewritten to incorporate the points made in the new foreword and correct my original misconception. I don't have time to do that rewrite this week, though.

Comment: @JeremyW.Sherman I figured it out, see my edit.  There was an extremely minor typo that completely changed how I was reading what you were saying.  I corrected it because I'm pretty sure I now understand what you meant.  Amazing how such a small thing can have such a big impact on meaning!  Cheers.